# Laravel. How to insert nested data into database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

It's very easy to insert a register when I have a JSON to insert an **Article** like this:

--JSON to insert--

```
{
    "title" : "a title",
    "content" : "some content",
    "user_id" : 3
}
```

To put it short, I create the route aiming to the store method of the controller and go for something simple like:

--ArticleController--

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $article = Article::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($article, 201);
}
```

But, what is the correct way to insert the data to store if I have something JSON:API complying like this?:

```
{
    "data": 
        {
            "type": "articles",
            "attributes": {
                "title": "a title",
                "content" : "some content",
                "user_id" : 3
            }
        }
}
```

What is the correct approach?

Comment: When the JSON data comes to the route manager, do you decide to which controller this request be directed based on the type in the JSON data?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi, not really. The input is always going to be the same, so it's always directed to the same controller. I don't know if I misunderstood your question (I'm very new to Laravel)

Comment: You understood well. Based on your comment then, I suggest you pass the json data by removing some parts and sending only the inputs, that way you can save the data in your controller in the way you already have tried. JSON data can be: {
    "title" : "a title",
    "content" : "some content",
    "user_id" : 3
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe it was so easy,

I just changed this:

```
    $article = Article::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($article, 201);
```

for this:

```
    $article = Article::create($request->data['attributes']);
    return response()->json($article, 201);
```

And that's it